# What does it mean to do something in a "type safe" way?

Tags: java, database, jdbc, ibatis, type-safety

An UPDATE statement can be configured in the Mapper XML file using the `<update>`
element as follows:

```
<update id="updateStudent" parameterType="Student">
UPDATE STUDENTS SET NAME=#{name}, EMAIL=#{email}, PHONE=#{phone}
WHERE STUD_ID=#{studId}
</update>
```

We can invoke this statement as follows:

```
int noOfRowsUpdated =
sqlSession.update("com.mybatis3.mappers.StudentMapper.updateStudent", 
student);
```

Instead of invoking the mapped statement using namespace and the statement id, you 
can create a Mapper interface and invoke the method in a "type safe" way as follows:

```
package com.mybatis3.mappers;
public interface StudentMapper
{
int updateStudent(Student student);
}
```

You can invoke the updateStudentstatement using the Mapper interface as follows:

```
StudentMapper mapper = sqlSession.getMapper(StudentMapper.class);
int noOfRowsUpdated = mapper.updateStudent(student);
```

My questions are: Why is the second way "type safe"? What does "type safe" mean here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is `type-safe` because `type-mismatch` errors will be detected at compile time and not runtime.

In the first example, you can pass any `Object` that isn't of type `Student` to the update method, it will compile fine but will fail at runtime.

In the second example you have to pass a valid `Student` object, otherwise, the code will fail to compile, and hence it's considered `type-safe`.

Comment: perfect answer of this question,i understand intantly,it is clear